# vue3 async setup() make my template not showing

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I cannot figure out why my data is not showing when I use async front of setup().

My component call a module that handle my api calls. From that api I receive a token that I want to display in my client, as a test.
I can display the token i'm requesting in the console.log but can't see it in the template area.

Login.vue :

```
<template>
  <h1>LOGIN</h1>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <div>My token: {{ token }}</div>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <div>Loading</div>
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>

<script>
import useLogin from '../modules/users';

export default {
  async setup() {
    const { login, token } = useLogin();
    await login();
    return { token };
  },
};
</script>
```

My module user.js

```
import api from '../services/Api';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function useLogin() {
  const token = ref(null);

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      token.value = await api.userLoginToken({
        email: 'user@test.com',
        password: '123123',
      });
      console.log(token.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error:', error);
      return new Error();
    }
  };
  return { login, token };
}
```

my api call is handled from api.js with axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default {
  async userLoginToken(credentials) {
    const token = await apiClient.post('/users/login/token', credentials);
    return token.data.token;
  },
};
```

The whole Login.vue is blank

IMPORTANT: the data is showing if I remove async from of setup() and await front of login().

But I don't understand why i cannot use async.

Answer (score 0):

Have to make the Suspense in the parent compoenent and move the fetch logic into a dedicated document to make it work.